# Unable to Delete row in CLoudboost

Tags: delete-row, cloudboost

Sometimes when I try to delete an entity, server takes too many time and finally it returns "Unable to delete". The curious thing is that if I go to dashboard, the row is deleted, but the error callback is launched after so many time.

This is the curl:

```
curl 'https://api.cloudboost.io/data/hixeyxddbwdy/Product' -X DELETE -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://builder.site.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en,es;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,ca;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'sessionID: fc8b1380-0470-11e6-905e-5d9430c98dbd' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: http://builder.site.com/projects/mygourmetlist/navigate' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"key":"742574d0-e26a-4352-9619-e402a9d1a5d4","document":{"_id":"mhCDnyRg","_tableName":"Product","ACL":{"read":{"allow":{"user":["all"],"role":[]},"deny":{"user":[],"role":[]}},"write":{"allow":{"user":["all"],"role":[]},"deny":{"user":[],"role":[]}}},"_type":"custom","expires":null,"type":"food","title":"Vall dhebron","brand":"","place":"","price":0,"category":"","userProduct":{"_id":"5sZ9Nw68","_tableName":"Product","ACL":{"read":{"allow":{"user":["all"],"role":[]},"deny":{"user":[],"role":[]}},"write":{"allow":{"user":["all"],"role":[]},"deny":{"user":[],"role":[]}}},"_type":"custom","expires":null,"type":"food","title":"Vall dhebron","brand":"","description":"","place":"","price":0,"rate":3,"category":"","user":{"_id":"VvNv0Bdp","_tableName":"User","expires":null,"_type":"user","fullName":"Angel","updatedAt":"2016-04-20T06:30:44.753Z","_version":1,"city":"Barcelona","ACL":{"read":{"allow":{"user":["all"],"role":[]},"deny":{"user":[],"role":[]}},"write":{"allow":{"user":["all"],"role":[]},"deny":{"user":[],"role":[]}}},"username":"angel.anglada.fuster@gmail.com","password":"h06/9edGFFO7+pkazOqBqRj3e1QMpWoFpsZkhnej0PDVj2n+NFUb2L3Dd4z0ykv3EvFG3oe/+u+Jb3w9rcvXTA==","email":"angel.anglada.fuster@gmail.com","createdAt":"2016-04-20T06:01:24.718Z"},"createdAt":"2016-04-20T06:39:33.671Z","updatedAt":"2016-04-20T06:39:33.671Z","_version":0},"user":{"_type":"user","_tableName":"User","_id":"LWsIkU9g"},"createdAt":"2016-04-20T07:41:07.293Z","updatedAt":"2016-04-20T07:41:07.293Z","_version":0}}' --compressed
```

Why is it taking this time?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm on it. Checking this out.

Comment: Is a test user in a test environment, don't worry about it. Thanks Nawaz.

Comment: Any advance on it? Today the error has reproducesd again

Comment: Hmm.. We're not able to reproduce it. Can I know your appId, table, and objectId where you're seeing this.

Comment: We're working on this. This should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

We've investigated this and have fixed this bug. Let me know if you still face this.